# Fill the combobox from a database table using php

Tags: php, database, combobox

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <center>
        <label for="groupx">Chose</label>
    </center>
    <select class="form-control" name="groupx" id="groupx">                                 
        <option value="Select">Chose from here....</option>
        <option value="php">php</option>
        <option value="html">html</option>
        <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
        <option value="CPP">CPP</option>
        <option value="Python">Python</option>
        <option value="vue">Vue</option>
        <option value="7">Cobobl</option>
        <option value="9">TEXT 4</option>
        <option value="CSS Text">CSS TEXT</option>
        <option value="responsive">Responsive</option>
    </select>
</div>

<?php 
    $default = mt_rand(1, count($countries));
    $countries = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `countries` order by `name` asc");
    while($row = $countries->fetch_assoc()):
        if($default == $row['id'])
            echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' selected>{$row['name']}</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    endwhile;
?>
```

Instead of static data I want the combobox to be populated from a database table
. I tried inserting but it doesn't work. I used a rule :

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the PHP script inside the table, like so:

```
<select>
  <option value="Select">Chose from here....</option> // This option is hard coded
<?php 
    $default = mt_rand(1, count($countries));
    $countries = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `countries` order by `name` asc");
    while($row = $countries->fetch_assoc()):
        if($default == $row['id'])
            echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' selected>{$row['name']}</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    endwhile;
?>
</select>
```

Be sure the script echos the correct amount of columns for the table.